# Check if number is automorphic

Tags: c++

I'm getting two numbers. First natural number n and second n - digit number. n range is `1<=n<=50000`. The problem is how can I do `n * n` on big numbers with for example `49000` digits. I was trying to do it on string, then I have array with each digit but what then? Write function that multiply n * n as string? I didn't have idea how to start it. Any ideas?

EDIT
I check if number is `automorphic` but how to edit it to work with numbers to `50000` digits?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int n, m = 10, a, b;

    cin >> n;

    b = m;
    while (n > b) {
        b *= m;
    }

    a = (n * n) % b;

    if (a == n)
        cout << "OK";
    else
        cout << "NO";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Write some code for your homework

Comment: For those who don't know, [automorphic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_number) is a number whose square "ends" in the same digits as the number itself.

Comment: I wrote program that checks if number is automorphic but it only works for for example long int. Is there any type that can store 50000 digits?

Comment: I just knew this was a 'no effort' before I opened it.

Comment: You have to rely on any BigInt library or do (part of) the multiplication yourself with string.

Comment: I was thinking about it. When I have number of digits is it possible to make just part of the multiplication and get the end of multiplicated number to compare it?

Comment: You can exclude all numbers that don't have 0,1,5,6 at the end because only those numbers muliplied give the same ending. Just to not calculate everything.

Answer (score 0):

They're various ways of dealing with big int in C++

- Using a library, like [`boost::xint`](http://www.oakcircle.com/xint_docs/), [Matt McCutchen bigint](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/), [InfInt](http://code.google.com/p/infint/), etc...
- Doing the needed operation by hand (if they're not much operations needed, you could implemented), in this case you only need **multiplication** (the **module** is with a power of 10 and can easily implemented), you could use for example `std::vector<unsigned char>` to store the digits of `n` and do the multiplication as teach in school, digit by digit, and report the last digits needed.

**Note:** you could do only part of the multiplication for obtaining the last digits needed (by take care with how much you need, for the digits needed). For 5000 digits, doing all the multiplication would finish lightning fast.

Comment: But when I have char how can I multiply it?

Comment: you used like if were a digit (0-9), and maintain the carry in the multiplications and inserted at the begin if necessary.